# Plotly offline html graphs export as CSV

Tags: plotly

I have recently worked with plotly and generated many offline graphs, which are now saved as HTML Graphs...

Now, I want to compare the graphs in a single graph and also get the data in a CSV format. Does any know how to do this. When opening the HTML Graph, i can only export the graph to a interactive web page form plotly, which does not seem very helpful to me...

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi Kongi, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: In particular you should specify which kind of data do you want to export. With dash you can use [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/allowing-users-to-download-csv-on-click/5550/4) suggestion.